# Loop through a list of list assigning variables

Tags: c#, json, list, loops, assign

I'm having trouble looping through my json trying to assign all my variables. I think it's because i don't get the loop through a list o list(Standings) to work. I'm sorry if my code is a bit messy with wierd variable names etc, but i have been going back and forth trying to figure it out but now i am at a point where i'm not know where i am anymore.

I'm getting a JSON string from an API. This is stored in a variable named "body", and this string is Deserialized into a string called "json". All good at this point. But now i'm trying to loop through it all and assign values to all my variables. This is how my code look like:

```
            List<Standings> s = new List<Standings>();

            var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(body);
            // Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(endpoint);
            var standing = json.api;


            //Console.WriteLine(standing.results.ToString());

           
            

            foreach (var stand in standing.Standings)
            {
                var al = new All
                {
                                  
                    matchsPlayed = stand.all.matchsPlayed,
                    win = stand.all.win,
                    draw = stand.all.draw,
                    lose = stand.all.lose,
                    goalsFor = stand.all.goalsFor,
                    goalsAgainst = stand.all.goalsAgainst 
                    

                };

                var ho = new Home
                {
                    matchsPlayed = stand.home.matchsPlayed,
                    win = stand.home.win,
                    draw = stand.home.draw,
                    lose = stand.home.lose,
                    goalsFor = stand.home.goalsFor,
                    goalsAgainst = stand.home.goalsAgainst

                };


                var aw = new Away
                {

                    matchsPlayed = stand.away.matchsPlayed,
                    win = stand.away.win,
                    draw = stand.away.draw,
                    lose = stand.away.lose,
                    goalsFor = stand.away.goalsFor,
                    goalsAgainst = stand.away.goalsAgainst


                };

                var standings = new List<Standings>();
                foreach (var b in standing.Standings)
                {
                    standings.Add(new Standings
                    {

                        rank = b.rank,
                        team_id = b.team_id,
                        teamName = b.teamName,
                        logo = b.logo,
                        group = b.group,
                        forme = b.forme,
                        status = b.status,
                        description = b.description,
                        all = al,
                        home = ho,
                        away = aw,
                        goalsDiff = b.goalsDiff,
                        points = b.points,
                        lastUpdate = b.lastUpdate
                    });
                }

                s.Add(new Api
                {
                    results = stand.results,
                    Standings = al
                });

            }
```

This is all my properties, i think this is all correct:

```
    public partial class All
{
    public int matchsPlayed { get; set; }
    public int win { get; set; }
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int lose { get; set; }
    public int goalsFor { get; set; }
    public int goalsAgainst { get; set; }
}

public partial class Home
{
    public int matchsPlayed { get; set; }
    public int win { get; set; }
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int lose { get; set; }
    public int goalsFor { get; set; }
    public int goalsAgainst { get; set; }
}

public partial class Away
{
    public int matchsPlayed { get; set; }
    public int win { get; set; }
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int lose { get; set; }
    public int goalsFor { get; set; }
    public int goalsAgainst { get; set; }
}

public partial class Standings 
{
    public int rank { get; set; }
    public int team_id { get; set; }
    public string teamName { get; set; }
    public string logo { get; set; }
    public string group { get; set; }
    public string forme { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public All all { get; set; }
    public Home home { get; set; }
    public Away away { get; set; }
    public int goalsDiff { get; set; }
    public int points { get; set; }
    public string lastUpdate { get; set; }
}



public partial class Api 
{
    public int results { get; set; }  
    public List<List<Standings>> Standings { get; set; }
}

public partial class Root 
{
    public Api api { get; set; }
}
```

This is the JSON i'm working with:

```
{"api":{"results":1,"standings":[[{"rank":1,"team_id":45,"teamName":"Everton","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/45.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"DWWWW","status":"same","description":"Promotion - Champions League (Group Stage)","all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":4,"draw":1,"lose":0,"goalsFor":14,"goalsAgainst":7},"home":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":2,"draw":1,"lose":0,"goalsFor":11,"goalsAgainst":6},"away":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":2,"draw":0,"lose":0,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":1},"goalsDiff":7,"points":13,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-23"},{"rank":2,"team_id":66,"teamName":"Aston Villa","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/66.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"WWWW","status":"same","description":"Promotion - Champions League (Group Stage)","all":{"matchsPlayed":4,"win":4,"draw":0,"lose":0,"goalsFor":12,"goalsAgainst":2},"home":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":2,"draw":0,"lose":0,"goalsFor":8,"goalsAgainst":2},"away":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":2,"draw":0,"lose":0,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":0},"goalsDiff":10,"points":12,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-23"},{"rank":3,"team_id":40,"teamName":"Liverpool","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/40.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"DLWWW","status":"same","description":"Promotion - Champions League (Group Stage)","all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":3,"draw":1,"lose":1,"goalsFor":13,"goalsAgainst":13},"home":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":2,"draw":0,"lose":0,"goalsFor":7,"goalsAgainst":4},"away":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":1,"draw":1,"lose":1,"goalsFor":6,"goalsAgainst":9},"goalsDiff":0,"points":10,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-23"},{"rank":4,"team_id":46,"teamName":"Leicester","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/46.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"LLWWW","status":"same","description":"Promotion - Champions League (Group Stage)","all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":3,"draw":0,"lose":2,"goalsFor":12,"goalsAgainst":8},"home":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":1,"draw":0,"lose":2,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":6},"away":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":2,"draw":0,"lose":0,"goalsFor":8,"goalsAgainst":2},"goalsDiff":4,"points":9,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-23"},{"rank":5,"team_id":42,"teamName":"Arsenal","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/42.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"LWLWW","status":"same","description":"Promotion - Europa League (Group Stage)","all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":3,"draw":0,"lose":2,"goalsFor":8,"goalsAgainst":6},"home":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":2,"draw":0,"lose":0,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":2},"away":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":1,"draw":0,"lose":2,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":4},"goalsDiff":2,"points":9,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-23"},{"rank":6,"team_id":39,"teamName":"Wolves","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/39.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"WWLLW","status":"same","description":null,"all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":3,"draw":0,"lose":2,"goalsFor":5,"goalsAgainst":7},"home":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":1,"draw":0,"lose":1,"goalsFor":2,"goalsAgainst":3},"away":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":2,"draw":0,"lose":1,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":4},"goalsDiff":-2,"points":9,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-23"},{"rank":7,"team_id":47,"teamName":"Tottenham","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/47.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"DWDWL","status":"same","description":null,"all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":2,"draw":2,"lose":1,"goalsFor":15,"goalsAgainst":8},"home":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":0,"draw":2,"lose":1,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":5},"away":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":2,"draw":0,"lose":0,"goalsFor":11,"goalsAgainst":3},"goalsDiff":7,"points":8,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-23"},{"rank":8,"team_id":49,"teamName":"Chelsea","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/49.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"DWDLW","status":"same","description":null,"all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":2,"draw":2,"lose":1,"goalsFor":13,"goalsAgainst":9},"home":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":1,"draw":1,"lose":1,"goalsFor":7,"goalsAgainst":5},"away":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":1,"draw":1,"lose":0,"goalsFor":6,"goalsAgainst":4},"goalsDiff":4,"points":8,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-23"},{"rank":9,"team_id":48,"teamName":"West Ham","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/48.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"DWWLL","status":"same","description":null,"all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":2,"draw":1,"lose":2,"goalsFor":11,"goalsAgainst":7},"home":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":1,"draw":0,"lose":1,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":2},"away":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":1,"draw":1,"lose":1,"goalsFor":7,"goalsAgainst":5},"goalsDiff":4,"points":7,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-23"},{"rank":10,"team_id":63,"teamName":"Leeds","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/63.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"LDWWL","status":"same","description":null,"all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":2,"draw":1,"lose":2,"goalsFor":9,"goalsAgainst":9},"home":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":1,"draw":1,"lose":1,"goalsFor":5,"goalsAgainst":5},"away":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":1,"draw":0,"lose":1,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":4},"goalsDiff":0,"points":7,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-23"},{"rank":11,"team_id":50,"teamName":"Manchester City","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/50.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"WDLW","status":"same","description":null,"all":{"matchsPlayed":4,"win":2,"draw":1,"lose":1,"goalsFor":7,"goalsAgainst":7},"home":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":1,"draw":0,"lose":1,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":5},"away":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":1,"draw":1,"lose":0,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":2},"goalsDiff":0,"points":7,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-23"},{"rank":12,"team_id":41,"teamName":"Southampton","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/41.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"DWWLL","status":"same","description":null,"all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":2,"draw":1,"lose":2,"goalsFor":8,"goalsAgainst":9},"home":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":1,"draw":0,"lose":1,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":5},"away":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":1,"draw":1,"lose":1,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":4},"goalsDiff":-1,"points":7,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-23"},{"rank":13,"team_id":34,"teamName":"Newcastle","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/34.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"LWDLW","status":"same","description":null,"all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":2,"draw":1,"lose":2,"goalsFor":7,"goalsAgainst":9},"home":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":1,"draw":0,"lose":2,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":8},"away":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":1,"draw":1,"lose":0,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":1},"goalsDiff":-2,"points":7,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-23"},{"rank":14,"team_id":52,"teamName":"Crystal Palace","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/52.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"DLLWW","status":"same","description":null,"all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":2,"draw":1,"lose":2,"goalsFor":6,"goalsAgainst":8},"home":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":1,"draw":1,"lose":1,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":3},"away":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":1,"draw":0,"lose":1,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":5},"goalsDiff":-2,"points":7,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-23"},{"rank":15,"team_id":33,"teamName":"Manchester United","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/33.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"WLWL","status":"same","description":null,"all":{"matchsPlayed":4,"win":2,"draw":0,"lose":2,"goalsFor":9,"goalsAgainst":12},"home":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":0,"draw":0,"lose":2,"goalsFor":2,"goalsAgainst":9},"away":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":2,"draw":0,"lose":0,"goalsFor":7,"goalsAgainst":3},"goalsDiff":-3,"points":6,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-23"},{"rank":16,"team_id":51,"teamName":"Brighton","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/51.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"DLLWL","status":"same","description":null,"all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":1,"draw":1,"lose":3,"goalsFor":9,"goalsAgainst":11},"home":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":0,"draw":0,"lose":2,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":6},"away":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":1,"draw":1,"lose":1,"goalsFor":6,"goalsAgainst":5},"goalsDiff":-2,"points":4,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-23"},{"rank":17,"team_id":60,"teamName":"West Brom","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/60.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"DLDLL","status":"same","description":null,"all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":0,"draw":2,"lose":3,"goalsFor":5,"goalsAgainst":13},"home":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":0,"draw":2,"lose":1,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":6},"away":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":0,"draw":0,"lose":2,"goalsFor":2,"goalsAgainst":7},"goalsDiff":-8,"points":2,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-23"},{"rank":18,"team_id":44,"teamName":"Burnley","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/44.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"DLLL","status":"same","description":"Relegation - Championship","all":{"matchsPlayed":4,"win":0,"draw":1,"lose":3,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":8},"home":{"matchsPlayed":1,"win":0,"draw":0,"lose":1,"goalsFor":0,"goalsAgainst":1},"away":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":0,"draw":1,"lose":2,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":7},"goalsDiff":-5,"points":1,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-23"},{"rank":19,"team_id":62,"teamName":"Sheffield Utd","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/62.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"DLLLL","status":"same","description":"Relegation - Championship","all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":0,"draw":1,"lose":4,"goalsFor":2,"goalsAgainst":7},"home":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":0,"draw":1,"lose":2,"goalsFor":1,"goalsAgainst":4},"away":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":0,"draw":0,"lose":2,"goalsFor":1,"goalsAgainst":3},"goalsDiff":-5,"points":1,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-23"},{"rank":20,"team_id":36,"teamName":"Fulham","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/36.png","group":"Premier League","forme":"DLLLL","status":"same","description":"Relegation - Championship","all":{"matchsPlayed":5,"win":0,"draw":1,"lose":4,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":12},"home":{"matchsPlayed":2,"win":0,"draw":0,"lose":2,"goalsFor":0,"goalsAgainst":6},"away":{"matchsPlayed":3,"win":0,"draw":1,"lose":2,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":6},"goalsDiff":-8,"points":1,"lastUpdate":"2020-10-23"}]]}}
```

I'm new to c# and object orienting programming but i'm pretty sure it's the List of list "standing" that's confusing it to me.

Comment: I might have missed something, but what problem are you facing?

Comment: `But now i'm trying to loop through it all and assign values to all my variables` why, you should deserialize into objects that represent your json return.

Comment: seems like `Api.Standings` should actually be a `list<Standings>`, not `List<List<Standings>>`. Anyway you confuse yourself by having a class that represents a **collection** of items. You pretty rarely need this, instead you may consider to have a collection of **single standing-instances, probably - whatever a standing should be (notice singular, no plural "s"). As of your currently code you have a list of lists of things that seems to represents a list itself -  so in fact a list of list of lists...